# How to take sum of small and capital letters values and put only one either in capital or small letter

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like below

```
sample = {'??': 2, 'N': 0, 'Y': 111, 'n': 0, 'n/a': 2, 'y': 55}
```

and I want the output as follows

```
sample_op = {'??': 2, 'N': 0, 'Y': 166, 'n/a': 2}
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried already so others will help you where you stuck

Comment: I have to count how many Y and how many N irrespective of their case i.e. small letters or capital letters

Comment: I tried this but I am getting only small case data not summing and caps     
samp_op = {k.lower(): v for k, v in ci_src_approved_count_dict.items()}

Comment: You should know that dictionary keys have to be unique ?

Comment: yes that is unique only. but output we can store in different dictionary with adding similar data elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try below code:

```
sample = {'??': 2, 'N': 0, 'Y': 111, 'n': 0, 'n/a': 2, 'y': 55}
samp_op = {}
for k, v in sample.items():
    lowercase = k.lower()
    if k!=lowercase and sample.has_key(lowercase):
        samp_op[lowercase] = sample[lowercase] + v
    else:
        samp_op[k] = v
print samp_op
```

The output is:

```
{'??': 2, 'y': 166, 'n/a': 2, 'n': 0}
```

Comment: @VikasD welcome.. accept my acnswer :)

Comment: alternative for python 3

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
sample = {'??': 2, 'N': 0, 'Y': 111, 'n': 0, 'n/a': 2, 'y': 55}
sample_op = defaultdict(int)

for (k,v) in sample.items():
    sample_op[k.upper()] += v

print sample_op
```

Prints:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'??': 2, 'N': 0, 'Y': 166, 'N/A': 2})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) and `.get` method:

```
sample = {'??': 2, 'N': 0, 'Y': 111, 'n': 0, 'n/a': 2, 'y': 55}
sample_op = {k.upper():sample.get(k.upper(),0)+v for k,v in sample.items()}
print(sample_op)
```

**Output:**

> `{'??': 4, 'N': 0, 'Y': 166, 'N/A': 2}`

**Note:** if you're using Python 2.6 or earlier, use:

```
sample = {'??': 2, 'N': 0, 'Y': 111, 'n': 0, 'n/a': 2, 'y': 55}
sample_op = dict((k.upper(), sample.get(k.upper(),0)+v) for (k, v) in sample.items())
print sample_op
```

**Output:**

> `{'??': 4, 'N': 0, 'Y': 166, 'N/A': 2}`

**What is going on?**

With *dict comprehension* you build your `dict` with new rules; i.e., if you want to generate a `dict` from another adding 2 to each of the first `dict`'s values, you can:

```
new_dict = {k:v+2 for k,v in first_dict.items()}
```

Or - in our example - we are creating a `dict` with this structure:

```
{k.upper(): # Key of our new dict: the uppercase of the old dict
sample.get(k.upper(),0)+v # We are asking for the value of our uppercase key in the old dict. If there's none, we assume as value 0. Then we add the value of the current key.
for k,v in sample.items()} # we iterate through all the key, value in our dict
```